# How do I loop through 2 columns?

Tags: php, loops, mysqli

I've got a table called tickets. The Tickets table has 4 columns: `user_id`, `ticket_id`, `subject`, `message`. I want to loop the ticket_id and subject of the logged in user. I want to echo it with foreach, but I cant get it to work. This is what I've got:

**Query:**

```
$showTheTickets = array();
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$getTickets = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE user_id = '$user_id'") OR die (mysqli_error($mysqli));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getTickets)){
    $showTicketID = $row['ticket_id'];
    $showTicketSubject = $row['subject']; 
}
```

**Code in the page:**

```
<?php foreach ($showTheTickets as $showTheTickets): ?> 
<div class="preview">
<?php echo $showTicketID ?>
<?php echo $showTicketSubject ?>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Anyones willing to help me? Thanks.

Comment: I find the construct `foreach ($somevar as $somevar)` as opposed to `foreach ($somevar as $anothervar)` unusual.

Comment: did you do a print_r($getTickets) ?? , the query is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$showTheTickets = array();
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$getTickets = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE user_id = $user_id") OR die (mysqli_error($mysqli));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getTickets)){

    $row = array( 'ticket_id' => $row['ticket_id'], 'subject' => $row['subject'] );
    $showTheTickets[] = $row;
}
```

And then:

```
<?php foreach ($showTheTickets as $stt): ?> 
<div class="preview">
<?php echo $stt['ticket_id'] ?>
<?php echo $stt['subject'] ?>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the values you get from the query and your `$showTheTickets` array remains empty.

You probably want something like:

```
$showTheTickets = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getTickets)){
    $showTheTickets[$row['ticket_id']] = $row['subject'];
}
```

and:

```
<?php foreach ($showTheTickets as $id => $subject): ?> 
<div class="preview">
<?php echo $id; ?>
<?php echo $subject; ?>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getTickets)){
    ?><div class="preview"><?
    echo $row['ticket_id'];
    echo $row['subject'];
    ?></div><?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to save  $showTicketID and $showTicketSubject in a array (could be the same array or 2 arrays) and then in the view show the arrays, like this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getTickets)){
    $array[$row['ticket_id']] = $row['subject'];
}
```

and the view:

```
<?php foreach ($showTheTickets as $ticketid => $ticketsubject): ?> 
<div class="preview">
<?php echo $ticketid ?>
<?php echo $ticketsubject ?>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```